# Text increment button using more than one id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a button which when pressed increases the selected text object, when I select the first object it gets its id and increases it perfectly problem is when i select another object it gets its id but for some reason retains the first selected id as well and changes both. I want it to explicitly change only the selected object. Any ideas how to resolve it with the code below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".click").click(function(){
            $('#id').val($(this).attr('id'));
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#font_size').val($(this).attr('font_size'), { id: id });

        $(".increase").click(function(){
            var currentSize = $("#"+id).css('font-size');
            var currentSize = parseFloat(currentSize)*1.2;
            $("#"+id).css('font-size', currentSize);
            alert(id);
        });
        });
    });

<input type="button" class="increase" value=" + ">

<?php

$result = mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FROM elements WHERE element_type ='text'") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        $id = $row['element_id'];

        $text_contents = $row['text_contents'];
        $textbox_contents = $row['textbox_contents'];

        $font_size = $row['font_size'];

?>

<p class="click" id="<?php echo $id ?>" style="position:absolute; font-size:<?php echo $font_size ?>px;">
<?php echo $text_contents ?></p>
<?php echo $textbox_contents ?></p>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: could be a nesting problem as you double close your `<p>` -> `<?php echo $text_contents ?></p><--here   <?php echo $textbox_contents ?></p><--and here`

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for replying, missed that one. I have removed one of them but still the same behaviour.